# How to call SpringHibernateMain?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new in Spring and Hibernate and trying to follow steps in the tutorial:
http://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial

But my application do nothing, just running. I have the same structure as author, but how to call main class that do all job SpringHibernateMain class? How it should works?

I use glassfish server:

```
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: /home/proger/Downloads/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1
Log File: /home/proger/Downloads/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.
Connected to server
[2017-03-18 04:44:19,863] Artifact rujava1:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2017-03-18 04:44:24,293] Artifact rujava1:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-03-18 04:44:24,293] Artifact rujava1:war exploded: Deploy took 4,430 milliseconds
```

But main method from SpringHibernateMain is not invoking.

Comment: You'd better use the official Spring + JPA guides, because this article not only uses completely obsolete libraries and APIs, but also doesn't configure and use Spring as it's supposed to be used, at all.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you are not able to run the main class?